# All files under `/usr/share/texmf` are removed, how to save?

Tags: texlive

I remove all files under `/usr/share/texmf` by mistake with `rm`(could I call it the curse of rm T_T). How could I do next to save the environment? Re-install? Or any other choice.

Comment: Need more information (at least the operating system). But assuming that's the distribution's TeX system, and not a separate install of TeX Live, and we're on a Debian-derived system, I'd just migrate to [installing the latest TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html). At least on one Ubuntu system I've checked, `/usr/share/texmf` is shared by at least 5 packages, each of which would have to be reinstalled.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks. My system is `Ubuntu`, yep a `Debian` derived distribution.

Comment: I'd just migrate using the instructions provided. Debian and Ubuntu's TeX Live packages are pretty old (TL 2009, unless you're running Debian wheezy or sid, or Ubuntu quantal). They're fine for most things, but there have been a ton of package updates and bug fixes since then, and most people here will assume you have an updated TeX system (or if nothing else, the answer will require updated versions of various packages).

Comment: Restore the files from your backup.

Comment: Did you consider removing the TeX related packages and re-adding them using you Linux package manager? How to do that is of course off-topic here but would be on topic for either Unix/Linux StackExchange or AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were in such situation I would upgrade to TeXLive 2011.  Installation of TexLive 2011 is no more difficult than [running one script](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall) and [creating dummy package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla).  Of course, it is needed to remove all old TexLive packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
```